# Hex-Rays IDA Decompiler

Tags: c++, decompiler, ida

I've been trying to decompile an exe file (or just one function, for all I care), and I've been running into the following error:
Decompilation failure:
FFFFFF: wrong basic type sizes in compiler settings
According to the manual, I should check these settings:

```
Some basic type sizes are incorrect. The decompiler requires that
sizeof(int) == 4
sizeof(bool) == 4
sizeof(enum) == 4
sizeof(long) == 4
sizeof(near pointer) == 4
Please check the type sizes in the Options, Compiler dialog box and modify        them if they are incorrect.
```

I have checked these settings, and they are set to the specified settings. Please note that I am missing the "sizeof(near pointer)" but I have a sizeof(short) and a sizeof(longlong) that aren't specified in the manual.

I'd be grateful for a fast resolution to this problem.

Comment: `sizeof(enum) == 4` ? What architecture are you trying to decompile? And you should be able to find out the pointer size too.

Comment: There is indeed an option for the pointer size, though it's set to unknown and I'm not sure which option to take: 
64 bit;
Near 16 bit, Far 32 bit;
Near 32 bit, Far 46 bit;

Comment: ... I think you´ve no idea what you´re doing. VTC.

Comment: Yup, pretty much. Thats kinda why I asked the question.

Comment: Is the `sizeof(bool)` 1 or 4 for your application?  On many implementations, it is 1 because that is the smallest size that can support the type.  Other implementations it could be the size of an integer because that is the processor's register width (word ).

Comment: It doesn't work with one, but it was set to four per default.

Comment: sizeof(short) can be 2
sizeof(longlong) 8
sizeof(near pointer) 4/8